# Making forward/backward Buttons in html for Table Data

Tags: php, mysql, linux, nginx, lamp

I have more than 200 data on this table based on HTML and MySQL database:

[image]

So, I would like to limit the number of entries shown to 15 and then have next and back button for every 15 other entries.

I am pretty new of LAMP environment, what would be the easiest way to do so?

Comment: I think the best way to create that is to use Datatable. Look at this tutorial for how to use that, https://newcodingera.com/datatable-using-codeigniter-part-1/

Comment: You can simply use DataTable js for quick pagination... https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using **LIMIT** in MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM <tbl_name> LIMIT 0,15; # Retrieve first 15 rows
```

The first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

You can use generic query like:

```
SELECT * FROM <tbl_name> LIMIT (page_no - 1) * items_per_page, items_per_page;
```

Where page_no will be initialized to 1 and items_per_page will be set to 15 in your case and on Clicking **Next** you should increment page_no and call the above query (decrement for **Previous** button)